# Cannot see the custom field created under account in Salesforce on Schema retrieval in Talend

Tags: salesforce, talend

In order to copy Salesforce production data to a sandbox environment, I created a custom field Migration_id which is an external id that will will be mapped as the Account Id.

However, when I use Talend to retrieve the schema, I am unable to see the new column field. Isn't this supposed to be instantaneous? Perhaps I'm missing something? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you see the Migration_id field in Salesforce itself?

Comment: Yes I can. But when I retrieve the schema in Talend I cannot see it as a column there.

Comment: Have you tried to insert the Migration_id field in the account's page layout and then retrieve the schema from talend?

Comment: This answer can give you more information:
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4674/custom-field-is-not-visible-editable-after-creation-professional-edition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not used Salesforce before but it looks like Talend bundles some prebuilt queries to Salesforce in the tSalesforceInput component.

You should be able to tick the "Manual input of SOQL query" box and define the query by hand. Make sure to align the component's schema with that of the SOQL query.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem. The issue was that the field was labeled differently from it's API name. So, for example I had a custom field called "Latest Account Date", however that is just a label for GUI, reporting, etc. The actual name was "Date_On_Account__c". You find this out by going to Setup>Customize>(Build) In may case it was Accounts > Fields